# how to add new device developer portal and add that in existing adhoc distribution for testing

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a adhoc distribution in which i have iPhone device added which works fine for testing but i want to add another iPad device and also run code on that so may i do this. I have added my device on provisional portal but how to use that for testing

Answer (score 1):

So, even though you said you added the iPad, I'm going to repeat that step for completeness here.

What you need to do is log into your Apple Developer account, and go to the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action), which should be accessible on the right side of the page.

Once here, click on "Devices" in the left navigation to bring up the Devices section. Here is where you add the iPad, as you said you already did. You can upload a file listing many devices, or add it manually.

Now you need to update your Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile. Click on "Provisioning" in the left navigation, and then click the Distribution tab. You should see your Ad Hoc Distribution Profile listed here. For the Ad Hoc profile, click the "Edit" button, and then click "Modify" in the popover that appears. This will bring up a list of all of the devices added to your Developer account. Tick the checkbox next to the new iPad device, and click save. This will bring you back to the Provisioning Portal. Refresh the page, and a "Download" button should appear next to the Ad Hoc Profile. Download the profile, and drag it into the Organizer in Xcode. You may need to delete the old Profile from the organizer before adding the updated one, and then re-select the updated profile in your "Build Settings" for the Ad Hoc configuration.